# 302 redirect misbehaviour

Tags: http, libcurl

I am using libCurl 7.15.1 which is pretty old.
When I do get Request, the server returns 302 as expected with redirected url in location header. But when I make get request again, it goes directly to redirected url and not the actual URL. This actually behaves like 301 premanent redirect.
I use followLocation option with TRUE value and MAXREDIRS set to 5.

Am I missing something here?

```
CURL* handle;
char* url = "www.google.com";
initialize()
{
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
}

perform()
{
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
}

main()
{
    CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
    initialize();
    perform();

    //Do something for some time (delay)
    perform();
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough details to allow us to give a good answer. There is no such logic in libcurl that you seem to imply. Also, there has never been a libcurl version 3.15.1, you may have meant 7.15.1...

Comment: Hi Daniel,  When I send get request using libCurl Handle, the server sends 302 found response with location containing the redirected URL.the libCurl again sends the GET request to te redirected URL and I get 200 OK response. When I use the same handle again for the same GET request, libCurl directly goes to redirected URL and the original URL. I made sure that get request is sent for original server and not the redirected server. And sorry for the libCurl version and I checked it is 7.15.1

Answer (score 0):

libcurl will always request the URL you set in the handle with [CURLOPT_URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTURL). If you don't update the URL, it will request that URL on all subsequent requests that re-use the handle.

The fact that transfer follows a Location: with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set in a previous request will not affect which URL it will request in the subsequent one.

You should possibly be aware of that when you're using such an old libcurl version, it doesn't copy the URL string from your code but will point to it so if you change the string in the mean time it will change sort of "under the hood" of what libcurl is aware of.

Comment: I have retained the URL string and livCurl will refer to proper memory location when I reuse the handle. But still the behavior is wrong for 302 response. please check the code above in problem description.  The second perform is going to redirected URL even though it received 302 response for 1st perform.

Comment: I have explained how libcurl works. You claim it does differently. Then it is either a bug in your ancient libcurl version or there's a bug in your program. I'm done here!